# Response Redirect not working after sending email

Tags: asp.net, email, response.redirect

I have a code that works with EPPlus library to modify some data from a dt to an excel file that it attachs itself and sends an email, and also downloads that file to the client sending it.

However from the following onClick method, it doesnt do anything but the SendModFile(), i think the text and stuff needs a postback thats why its not changing, that i can take away, but i must disable the button for the process not to send more than one email and redirect to the main menu, how can i acomplish this.

```
 Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Label1.Visible = True
    Button2.Enabled = False
    Label1.Text = "Sending..."

    SendModFile()
    Label1.Text = "Sent"

    Response.Redirect("~/Main.aspx")
End Sub
```

Edit:
This is the end of the SendModFile() that lets download the file after sending the email, is there a way to optimize this, i believe this part is the one messing up due to Response.End()

```
Response.Clear()
Response.Buffer = True
Response.ContentType = "application/application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExcelFileName.xlsx")
Response.BinaryWrite(memStream2.ToArray())
Response.End()
```

Comment: Does this line gets executed `Label1.Text = "Sent"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call [Response.End](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end(v=vs.110).aspx), that's the end of the response. You can't then do a redirect.

One workaround is to have the user download the file in a separate HTTP request by providing a link or button that downloads the file, so that you still main control over the page they're accessing.

Comment: Or use `Server.Transfer()`

Comment: i also tried using server.transfer does nothing sadly, @mason shouldn't respnse.end act as an end of process     ( SendModFile()) not the whole funtionality?

Comment: @JavierM I linked to the documentation for it. Basically, if you call Response.End, you need to be done writing to the response. Did you try my workaround?

Comment: i am onto that, i took out the file downloading and it works the redirect*, however it does not disable the button, how can i acomplish that?

Comment: @JavierM Why would you need to disable the button if you're redirecting?

Comment: @mason on the same note, the windows keeps being blocked by the browsers, is there a way to avoid this, because otherwise it wont work

Comment: Because people are so impatient, that clicks several times a button to make it "work faster" and since it also doesnt update the label text there's no way to tell the user.. "hey its working can you wait while i redirect " i might just redirect to another page that it says please be patient while i redirect. also read my problem onto download the file in a separate tab

Comment: 1) offer link/button that opens in a new tab that directly downloads the file (doesn't have to be a new tab) 2) Use JavaScript on the client to client to disable the link/button when clicked

Comment: I might be doing that in the end, however is there another method to download a file from memstream or is there a better way to do it?